# Connecting to Amazon RDS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL RDS server running, but the only way I can connect to it is using pgAdmin III.

Connecting via psql command line just hangs forever. Using node.js pg library doesn't work either (my end goal is to have my node server talk to it.)

The RDS server is in a VPC with every inbound connection allowed, too. So no connection denied errors, just no responses apparently.
pgAdmin III works fine for some reason, no SSL or SSH Tunnelling.

This is the error I get from nodeJS:

connection error {
name: 'error',
length: 91,
severity: 'FATAL',
code: '3D000',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
file: 'postinit.c',
line: '775',
routine: 'InitPostgres' }

Comment: Presumably the settings are different. Either that, or you have some dodgy 3rd party software firewall on your PC filtering outbound connections and you've whitelisted PgAdmin...

Comment: What settings could possibly different? I just used default settings on pgAdmin to connect to same endpoint, port, and db